# Switch statement is not working as expected, even if syntax is probably fully correct

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a c# beginner and was working on a game. What I had to do was, if the user chose a certain level, he could get a reward. Here is my code:

```cs
void ShowLevelReward()
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case 1:
                Terminal.WriteLine("Reward 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                Terminal.WriteLine("Reward 2");
                break;
            case 3:
                Terminal.WriteLine("Reward 3");
                break;
            default:
                Debug.LogError("Invalid Input!");
                break;
        }
```

The problem is that I am getting an error in the line where `case 1:` is written saying

> Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 1:') to another [Assembly-CSharp]

I have added all the "breaks" and everything, but I am still getting the error.
One more thing that I want to point out, when I choose level 3, I am not getting any output (expected output being "reward 3")
Any suggestions of how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to Clean/Rebuild your project after editing your code?

Comment: Statements like _"Switch statement is not working as expected"_ translates into, I don't really understand how does switch statement work.

Comment: This is very weird. The code seems ok to me. Maybe Unity is caching a previous version of the file, so you are keeping executing the previous code. Could you reproduce this issue by creating a new Unity project with just this code?

Comment: Does the error come from the unity3d logging window?

Answer (score -1):

I think I know why.

You're not catching a value for variable "level". This is either going to be passed as an argument through the method or you will catch it inside the method, but I think you want to pass it as an argument through method ShowLevel().

```
void ShowLevel(int level)
```

Or, conversely, you can set the value of level from inside method ShowLevel():

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a level: ");
string sLevel = Console.ReadLine(); // capture this value as a string
int level = int.Parse(sLevel); // parse as integer and set level as an integer
```

Don't feel bad - I make mistakes like this all the time.

Comment: EDIT: How the compiler didn't catch this is beyond me.

Comment: `level` can as well be a field or property in the class .. it doesn't need to be a local variable or argument of the method ...

Comment: In this context he's using it as a local variable, or at least he seems to be if his code is to be taken at face value.

Comment: oops! Actually I forgot to mention that I had already declared the level variable at the start of my code, I am extremely sorry I forgot to mention that piece of info, but the error still persists... can you please suggest a fix?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do - do you want to pass the level variable through the argument or do you want to declare it locally? I've given you a fix either way.

If you've declared this at the start of your code (and outside the method), void ShowLevel(int level) is the way to go.